# Apply different different data colors to different charts in power bi theme creation

Tags: powerbi

I am using PowerBi February release.

I am trying to create custom theme (.json file). I want to have different data colors for different charts and not the global/common data colors for all charts.

Suppose for line chart colors are "red,green,blue" then for pie chart colors are different, lets say "yellow,grey,purple".

Can you please suggest how to create a theme based on above requirement.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible to create a custom theme that pre-assigns each color to a bar or piece of a pie chart.  You can for KPI and some of the other visuals, but not pie or bar (aka stacked column chart)

The current workaround is very easy though.  Follow these steps:

1)  [As suggested by this blog](https://powerbi.tips/2017/03/color-themes-import/), create a custom theme with your desired colors.   Using [this online tool](https://powerbi.tips/tools/color-theme-generator/), I was able to make a minimum theme file from your requirements:

```
{
    "name":"MyTheme1",
    "dataColors":["#ff5624", "#21ff13", "#0009db", "#fff780", "#d3d3d3", "#7d00b6"]
}
```

2)  Save this as `yourtheme.json` and import the file in the Ribbon using **Themes->Switch Theme->Import Theme**

3) Then you would need to go to the bar chart and pie visual and assign the colors individually:

- For the Pie Chart - click the **paint roller** found in the visualizations pane and expand **Data Colors**.  Then assign the color to the values for each pie piece. (see image for the colors from your theme.)

[image]

- For bar chart (aka stacked column chart) click the **paint roller** found in the visualizations pane and expand **Data Colors**.  Then set the **Show All** setting to **On**.  Then assign the color to the values for each bar.

The image below is a power bi report with bar and pie charts colored with the colors from your imported theme file.

[image]

Comment: You are welcome.  If you find any of the information useful, do you mind giving me an upvote?  It’s common practice here.  Thanks.